# Determining output of an array implementation with class and constructor

Tags: java

Im trying to understand whats being iterated and went through a visualizer but after getting the [0,2,4,6,8,0,0,0,0,0] from the main Im having trouble understanding how the final output is [2,0,2,0...etc] Im assuming the "if (n > (arr.length - 2)) return;" is ignored since 5 is not bigger than 8, but then I get lost. If anyone could explain that I would appreciate it.

```
public class Class1{
    public static void shiftTwoOver(int[] arr, int n) {
        if (n > (arr.length - 2)) return;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            arr[i+2] = arr[i];
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) a[i] = 2*i;
        shiftTwoOver(a,5);
        for (int i = 2; i < 7; ++i) System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/java_visualize/#mode=display is the visualizer I used.

Comment: Try doing this by hand (it's called "hand execution.")  Make sure to follow that shift loop carefully and you'll see why it gets copied that way.

Comment: If you want to shift the array elements to the right in place, you have to do it from right to left. Your `shiftTwoOver()` function is overwriting the values on the right which you haven't read yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop is executed five times, because n=5

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        arr[i+2] = arr[i];
```

1. arr[2] = arr[0] which is 0;
2. arr[3] = arr[1] which is 2;
3. arr[4] = arr[2] which is 0 from the first execution;
4. arr[5] = arr[3] which is 2 from the second execution;
5. arr[6] = arr[4] which is 0 from the third execution;

And later it's only printed out from index 2 to 6.

Answer (score 0):

The array you are passing in is a dynamic array of size 10, and for the parameters you are passing in 5. So the  if (n > (arr.length - 2)) return; will never trigger because n is less then (arr.length -2) = 8.

Furthermore the data is corrupted when you arr[i+2] = arr[i] because you initialized the array with a[i] = 2*i from a[0] to a[4]. I think the goal is to move all 5 data elements two spaces over? So when you make arr[2] = arr[0] remember you just deleted all the data at arr[2] and replaced it with arr[0].

Since that loops five times understand what you have now say initially arr[0] = "bob"  now you will have arr[0] = bob and arr[2] = bob.  Note that arr[0] wasnt erased so you technically didn't move anything and just copied data over. Repeat that again for arr[3] = arr[1] and once again on the next step you will do arr[4] = arr[2] remember in arr[2] there was "bob" now you have arr[4] = "bob" as well.

So ultimately you have arr[0] = arr[2] = arr[4] = "bob". Hence, the data was never shifted two rows. Thats why you have 2 0 2 0 2 0  repeating.